# Angular directive wrapping ng-messages

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created an angular directive to handle showing of error messages. It wraps the built in directives ng-messages & ng-message-exp. (Reason for doing this is to create a custom popover error message control)

To achieve this I have created a parent controller that keeps track of the error messages. It houses a controller that has a method to add messages, which is called from the child directive(s).

When I specify the form ng-messages=\"myForm.myEmail.$error\" role=\"alert\" ng-show=\"myForm.myEmail.$invalid && myForm.myEmail.$dirty\" on the root element in the directive template for the popoutValidation directive. I.e. hard coding it so that it maps to the form and element on the page, it works correctly and shows the error messages correctly for required or invalid email. however, when I try to pass in the form name and the control in question dynamically it stops working. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

```
<ng-form name="myForm">
      <input type="email" name="myEmail2" ng-model="vm.name" required />
      <popout-validation position="left" form="myForm" for="myEmail2">
          <popout-validation-message type="required" message="This is requireddddd." />
         <popout-validation-message type="email" message="invalid email address." />
      </popout-validation>

   </ng-form>
```

And the following code:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngMessages"]);

app.controller("myCtrl", function() {
   var vm = this;
   vm.name = "ee";
});

app.directive("popoutValidationMessage", function() {
   return {
      scope: {
         type: "@",
         message : "@"
      },

      require: "^popoutValidation",
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
         ctrl.addMessage(attr.type, attr.message);
      }
   }
});

app.directive("popoutValidation", function() {
   return {
      require: "^form",
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      template: "<div class=\"error\" ng-messages>" +
         "<div ng-repeat=\"errorMessage in errorMessages\">" +
         "<div ng-message-exp=\"errorMessage.type\">{{ errorMessage.text }}</div>" +
         "</div>" +
         "<div ng-transclude></div>" +
         "</div>",
      compile: function(element, attr) {
         //ng-messages=\"myForm.myEmail.$error\" role=\"alert\" ng-show=\"myForm.myEmail.$invalid && myForm.myEmail.$dirty\"

         var formStr = attr.form + "." + attr.for;
         element.attr("ng-messages", formStr + "." + "$error");
         element.attr("ng-show", formStr + "." + "$invalid && " + formStr + "." + "$dirty");


      },
      controller: function($scope) {
         $scope.errorMessages = [];

         this.addMessage = function(type, message) {
            $scope.errorMessages.push({
               type: type,
               text: message
            });
         };
      }
   }
});
```

http://codepen.io/mantisimo/pen/ojbqoa?editors=101

Answer (score 0):

There maybe two ways to handle error message with directives.

1. use $rootScope. when directive template set variable like {{$root.msg}}, then can set $rootScope.msg in the controller. Of course, the variable in $rootScope can be rendered in directive.
2. Better practice is with no scope pollution. Then this way comes. First create directive like this.

```js
app.directive("toasterContainer", function($timeout, $compile, $sce, toaster) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: "E",
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$on('toaster-newToast', function() {
                scope.toast = toaster.toast;
                $timeout(function() {
                    toaster.toast.display = false;
                }, toaster.toast.timeout);
            });
        },
        templateUrl: "/static/shop/snippets/toaster_container.html"
    }
});
```

---

Then create service like this `toaster`.

```js
define([], function() {
    var toaster = function($timeout, $rootScope) {
        this.pop = function(type, msg, timeout) {
            var type = (typeof type === "undefined") ? "info" : type;
            var msg = (typeof msg === "undefined") ? "" : msg;
            var timeout = (typeof timeout === "undefined") ? 5000 : timeout;
            this.toast = {
                type: type,
                msg: msg,
                timeout: timeout,
                display: true
            }
            $rootScope.$broadcast('toaster-newToast');
        },
        this.initPop = function(type, msg, timeout) {
            var scope = this;
            $timeout(function() {
                scope.pop(type, msg, timeout);
            }, 300);
        }
    }
    toaster.$inject = ['$timeout', '$rootScope'];
    return toaster;
})
```

Then in controllers, you can simple use `toaster` service to pop error messages like this.

```js
toaster.pop("success", msg);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion... I was looking for a fix to the code above. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.... Just needed to compile the result

```
compile: function(element, attr) {

         var formStr = attr.form + "." + attr.field;
         element.attr("ng-messages", formStr + "." + "$error");
         element.attr("ng-show", formStr + "." + "$invalid && " + formStr + "." + "$dirty");

         return {
            post : function(scope, element, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
               $compile(element)(scope);
            }
         }
      }
```